# How to Create Addition program for windows store app in visual studio 2012 using c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to make a simple addition windows store app using c++ in visual basic.

1) I added 3 textboxes, (1 for 1st num, 2nd for 2nd num, and 3rd for showing addition result.).

2) And I added one button which when clicked adds the data of both textboxes and shows in result.

So I want to get input from the user in textboxes, and when ADD button is clicked, Result is shown in Result(3rd) textbox.

How to convert num1.text and num2.text to integer and add it?

Here is my XAML Code:

```
<Page
    x:Class="winstore_c__1stapp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:winstore_c__1stapp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="534,179,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Addition" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="77" Width="438" FontSize="24"/>

        <TextBox x:Name="num1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="301,301,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="195" AcceptsReturn="True" TextChanged="num1_TextChanged"/>

        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="153,301,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="1st Number" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="32" Width="114" FontSize="14"/>

        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="684,301,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="2nd number" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="32" Width="114"/>

        <TextBox x:Name="num2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="803,301,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="195"/>

        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="210,529,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Addition is:-" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="43" Width="116" FontSize="20"/>

        <TextBox x:Name="num3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="358,529,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="306" TextChanged="c_TextChanged"/>

        <Button x:Name="mybutton" Content="Click to ADD" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="522,421,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button_Click_1" Width="153"/>

</Grid>
</Page>
```

This kinda issues of getting inputs from user and manipulating them are very important for Begginers like me.

Comment: You should post your xaml as text so that other people can copy it if needed. Be sure to put 4 spaces in front of each line.

Comment: Do you want a Pure C++ solution, a C# solution or a *Managed* C++ solution?

Answer (score 0):

you need to do something like this:

```
int firstNumber = Int32.TryParse(num1.Text, 0);
int secondNumber = Int32.TryParse(num2.Text, 0);
num3.Text = (firstNumber + secondNumber).ToString();
```

Comment: When I compiler for pure C++, I can't find the `Int32` class.  Which standard C++ header file do I need to include.

Comment: it is in System... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1

Comment: System is not a C++ standard library. -- *The C++ Standard Library: A Tutorial and Reference* by Nicolai M. Josuttis

Answer (score 0):

You could use `std::istringstream`:

```
std::istringstream inp(num1.text);
int value;
inp >> value;
```

There are other functions for converting text to number.  Search the web and StackOverflow for "C++ convert text number".

Comment: How to declare inp??                                                                                                                                                    I wrote it in click event..                                                       void winstore_c__1stapp::MainPage::Button_Click_1(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
 std::istringstream inp(num1.text);




}            But it shows an red ubderline as error on inp. Do i need to include an header file?? What i hav to include??

Comment: Use `#include <stringstream>`.  You can always search a good C++ book or reference site for `std::istringstream`.